# ODE45: Give different results from `expm` in sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, ode, differential-equations

`K` is a large sparse matrix and `y` is a vector. At a particular timestep `dt` from `t1` to `t1+dt`:

Method1: 
The `expm` leads to:

```
K = ...
y = ...    
y = expm(-1i*dt*K)*y; %new y
```

Method2:

The `ode45` gives:

```
K = ...
y = ... 
y0 = y;
[T, Y] = ode45(@(t,y)dy(y,K),[t1 t1+dt],y0);
y = Y(end,:).'; %new y
```

where:

```
function ydot = dy(y,K)
ydot = -1i*K*y;
```

The two method gives different result for large sparse matrix. Which is the correct one?

Comment: Did you try to reduce error tolerance or integration step size of ode45?

Comment: @AVK no i did not. do you know the reason behind?

Comment: Possibly ode45 loses precision. Try to play with `AbsTol`, `RelTol` and `MaxStep` integration options

Comment: @AVK thanks. is `y = expm(-1i*dt*K)*y` the most correct (theoretical) solution, while `ode45` is approximation to the differential equation?

Comment: ode45 always gives approximation to real solution with an error depending on integration step size. ODE solver (ode45 or another one) calculates the step size automatically to  satisfy `AbsTol` and `RelTol` requirements. However, this calculation is, in turn, approximate and the required precision is, in practice, may be not garanteed.

Comment: Expm calculation is based on linear algebra methods. It uses no iterative steps, unknown parameter estimations etc.So it is more reliable than ode solving

Comment: @AVK is there any way i can make ode45 more accurate for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above, there is no way to 100% guarantee the correctness of ode solver results. But you can:

- manually set the upper bound for integration step size;
- try using a
  stiff solver (ode15s,ode23t etc);
- supply the Jacobian matrix or the
  Jacobian pattern for `dy(y,K)` to improve the solver accuracy.

---

Here is an example of manually setting the maximum step size:

```
options= odeset('MaxStep',1e-3); % some experimentally obtained value here
[T, Y] = ode45(@(t,y)dy(y,K),[t1 t1+dt],y0,options);
```

[Here is the description](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/ref/odeset.html#1023074) of `Jacobian` and `Jpattern` options. Note that you can't use them with `ode45`, you should use another solver